# Disable pasting of images into wordpress editor

Tags: visual-editor

I have a user who loves to do this, It works fine for the website, but when it gets transferred over to the newsletter it breaks the newsletter.

Is it possible to disable pasting of images into the WordPress editor without removing the visual editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into TinyMCE's paste function and filter user actions using javascript. So yes it is possible. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste